# I'm trying to use strcmp() to sort a string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I have a homework challenge that is giving me a headache.  The problem is:

> Build a program that uses an array of strings to store the following names:
>   * "Florida"
>   * "Oregon"
>   * "California"
>   * "Georgia"
>   Using the preceding array of strings, write your own sort() function to display > each state's name in alphabetical order using the strcmp() function.

Here is my code that is giving me issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//function prototype
int sort(char *, char *);

int main() 
{
    char *strStates[] = {"Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia"};
    char *strSorted[] = {0};
    int x;

    printf("\nThe list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order: ");

    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
    {
        printf("\n%s", strStates[x]);
    }

    sort(strStates[x], strSorted[x]);

    printf("\nThe list of states sorted alphabetically are: ");

    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
    {
        printf("\n%s", strStates[x]);
    }

    return 0;

}//end main

//function definition
int sort(char *string1, char *string2)
{
    int x;
    int y;

    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
    {
        for (y = 1; y < 4; y++) 
        {
            if ((strcmp(string1[x], string1[y])) > 0) 
            {
                strcpy(string2, string1[x]);
                strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
                strcpy(string[y], string2);
            }//end if

       }//end inner for loop

    }//end outer for loop

}//end sort()
```

I have a whole series of errors while compiling:

```
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:45:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
                    if ((strcmp(string1[x], string1[y])) > 0) 
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
                                &  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/string.h:77:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      strcmp(const char *, const char *);
                        ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:45:28: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
                    if ((strcmp(string1[x], string1[y])) > 0) 
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
                                            &  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/string.h:77:39: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      strcmp(const char *, const char *);
                                      ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:47:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
                            strcpy(string2, string1[x]);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
                                            &  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:33: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                            ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:48:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                            strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:53: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                                ^  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:54: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)
                                                 ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:48:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
                            strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                   &  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:27: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                      ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:48:24: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
                            strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
                                               &  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:33: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                            ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:49:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'; did you mean 'string1'?
                            strcpy(string[y], string2);
                                   ^~~~~~
                                   string1  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:27: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                      ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:36:16: note: 'string1' declared here
int sort(char *string1, char *string2)
           ^  
Chapter_8_Challenge_3.c:49:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'string'
                            strcpy(string[y], string2);
                                   ^  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:53: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
  __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                                ^  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/secure/_common.h:39:54: note: expanded from macro '__darwin_obsz'
#define __darwin_obsz(object) __builtin_object_size (object, _USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 1 ? 1 : 0)  
                                                 ^
6 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: What issues exactly?

Comment: What problems are you having?  No one is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am getting a whole series of errors during the compile.

Comment: Such as?  Edit your main post and include what you've tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: "I am getting a whole series of errors" is of little value. Post the errors and the lines associated with that errors.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the errors.

Comment: Now look at your post. Does it look remotely like your compiler output? Can you tell where one error message ends and the other one begins?

Comment: Try removing `char *strSorted[] = {0};` and changing `int sort(char *, char *);` to `void sort(char **);`, `sort(strStates[x], strSorted[x]);` to `sort(strStates);` and `int sort(char *string1, char *string2)
{` to `void sort(char **string1)
{ char string2[64];`

Comment: Remove Oregon.  Nothing good ever came out of Oregon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the error with `sort` function arguments you also should consider usage of `strcpy`. You cannot copy a string literal into another string literal, since they are read only.

Do you really need to copy strings? You have input array of pointers to strings. You can sort only those pointers without touching actual strings.

You can just pass that array of pointers and sort them:

```
void sort(char *strStates[])
{
    int x, y;

    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
    {
        for (y = x + 1; y < 4; y++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(strStates[x], strStates[y])) > 0) 
            {
                char *tmp = strStates[x];
                strStates[x] = strStates[y];
                strStates[y] = tmp;
            }//end if
       }//end inner for loop
    }//end outer for loop
}//end sort()
```

It can be called as `sort(strStates)`.

You can also think about passing array size into that function to avoid magic numbers `3` and `4`: `void sort(char *strStates[], int size)`.

Comment: Thank you @OrestHera that worked perfectly!  I think I was confusing myself with trying to use another string array to copy the sorted values to.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In your function `sort` -

```
if((strcmp(string1[x],string1[y]))>0) //string1[x] is of type char-Wrong argument to strcmp 
        {
            strcpy(string2, string1[x]);          // same problem as aboce for all 
            strcpy(string1[x], string1[y]);
            strcpy(string[y], string2);
        }//end if
```

This `string1` is already a `char *` and `string1[x]` will be of type `char` . So this invokes *undefined behaviour*.

**2.** In `main` -

```
 for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
{
    printf("\n%s", strStates[x]);
}

sort(strStates[x], strSorted[x]);
```

Maybe you intend to pass array of `char` pointers (`strStates`) to function as first parameter and (`strSorted`) as second parameter. Then the above problem in `sort` will also be solved.

**3.** At last you function `int sort()` does not `return` anything , so again you got yourself *UB*.

***Note*** - The error you get are because of passing `char` to string function .

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort` function recieves 2 strings as parameter, so `if ((strcmp(string1[x], string1[y])) > 0)` is trying to compare two char with `strcmp`. Your sort function should be more like this:

```
void sort(char **unsortedStrings){
    int x;
    int y;
    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
    {
        for (y = x+1; y < 4; y++) 
        {
            if ((strcmp(unsortedStrings[x], unsortedStrings[y])) > 0) 
            {
                // There is no need to use strcpy here, just re-order the pointers
                char *tmp = unsortedStrings[x];
                unsortedStrings[x] = unsortedStrings[y];
                unsortedStrings[y] = tmp;
            }//end if

      }//end inner for loop

   }//end outer for loop
}//end sort()
```

Also your sort functions says it should be returning an int, but nothing is being returned. Either you return something (Like `return 1` if everything ok or `return 0` in case of failure) or you should declare it as `void`

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. E.  You're help cleared the errors but the list doesn't sort.  When I run my modified code it compiles as follows:  
  
The list of states before being sorted in alphabetical order:  
Florida  
Oregon  
California  
Georgia  
  
The list of states sorted alphabetically are:  
California  
Oregon  
Florida  
Georgia

Comment: Didn't notice it but loops starting indeces are wrong. I have just edited it, try now

Comment: Out of range: `unsortedStrings[y]` for `y = 4`

Comment: You're right added the `<=` in the for cycles while fixing it. I'll edit